# Build android arm64 native library using qmake

Tags: android, c++, qt, android-ndk, qmake

I'm using qmake for generating make files for my native library (just generate make files, no usage of Qt libs).

There are only android armv5, armv7 and x86 supported by qt, so when I build my library using qmake from any qt package above I can build only armv5, armv7 and x86 libraries.

Is there a way to specify another target architecture for qmake (arm64 of mips for example)?

Answer (score 0):

you need to build the arm64-v8a library yourself,

and use your arm64-v8a qmake to build your own library.

this is mac build version

```
git clone git://code.qt.io/qt/qt5.git qt5
cd qt5
perl init-repository

./configure \
-confirm-license \
-opensource \
-xplatform android-g++ \
-nomake tests \
-nomake examples \
-android-ndk /usr/local/Cellar/android-ndk/r10e \
-android-sdk ~/Documents/android-sdk-macosx \
-android-ndk-host darwin-x86_64 \
-android-toolchain-version 4.9 \
-android-arch arm64-v8a \
-android-ndk-platform android-21 \
-skip qtdeclarative \
-skip qttranslations \
-skip qtserialport \
-no-warnings-are-errors \
-no-compile-examples \
-no-sql-mysql \
-no-sql-psql \
-prefix ~/Documents/Qt/android_arm64-v8a \
-prefix-install \
-openssl \
-I /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2k/include -L /usr/local/Cellar/openssl/1.0.2k/lib

make -j4
make -j4 install
```

you also can download arm64-v8a library here: https://github.com/LightZam/Qt-Library